# Should old OAuth 2.0 refresh tokens be revoked

Tags: oauth-2.0

In principle, should any existing OAuth 2.0 refresh tokens (for a given client/user combination) be revoked when a new refresh token is issued following a password grant authentication?

I can't find anything specific in the spec. Would it be legitimate to reissue the same refresh token for subsequent password logins?

Answer (score 0):

The [OAuth Spec section-6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6) specifies that:

> The authorization server MAY issue a new refresh token, in which case
> the client MUST discard the old refresh token and replace it with the
> new refresh token.  The authorization server MAY revoke the old
> refresh token after issuing a new refresh token to the client.  If a
> new refresh token is issued, the refresh token scope MUST be
> identical to that of the refresh token included by the client in the
> request.

---

So there is no requirement that you MUST issue a new refresh token and revoke the old one, however, for the same reason that access_tokens expire it would be a good idea to issue new ones. A compromised refresh_token would only be valid until the subsequent refresh. This would allow a developer to revoke the refresh token should it ever be leaked.