# Is it ever reasonable to revoke a refresh token after a period of time?

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token, onlinebanking

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937597/should-old-oauth-2-0-refresh-tokens-be-revoked) I wonder should the server ever just revoke refresh token after a certain period of time and just force the user to login again? I can't remember when was the last I had to enter my login credentials for my Gmail.

What do **banks** (or any site that stores sensitive data) do if a given user refreshes their token for 200 days? Should they allow the user to continue to use the site? I understand it involves user interaction, so it's not something that is easy to automate.

Answer (score 0):

The refresh token lifetime (or enablement) is decided by an administrator who controls the assets - not by the end user.

Use of short lived tokens is preferred - it is technically simple and zero maintenance

Comment: a given refresh token has a certain expiry time. If you refresh the refresh token, then it will all start over again. Right? How do you resolve that? Or that doesn''t need solving?

Comment: Yes. But RTs can be renewed. Right? If you keep renewing it before it gets expired then it will continue to work. Right?

Comment: @Honey - As fas as I understand, a refresh token cannot be renewed. The Access token can be refreshed using the refresh token, but if the refresh token expires, the user has to do the login procedure again. Refresh tokens can be valid for a very long time though, or they can never expire at all.